# pthreads program works for some time and then stalls

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

There is a program I am working on that, after I launch it, works for some time and then stalls. Here is a simplified version of the program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t* thread_handles;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t  cond_var = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int thread_count;
const int some_count = 77;
const int numb_count = 5;
int countR = 0;

//Initialize threads
void InitTh(char* arg[]){
    /* Get number of threads */
    thread_count = strtol(arg[1], NULL, 10);
    /*Allocate space for threads*/
    thread_handles =(pthread_t*) malloc (thread_count*sizeof(pthread_t));
}

//Terminate threads
void TermTh(){
    for(long thread = 0; thread < thread_count; thread++)
        pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], NULL);
    free(thread_handles);
}

void* DO_WORK(void* replica) {
    /*Does something*/
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    countR++;
    if (countR == numb_count) pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond_var);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

//Some function
void FUNCTION(){
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    for(int k = 0; k < some_count; k++){
        for(int j = 0; j < numb_count; j++){
            long thread = (long) j % thread_count;
            pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL, DO_WORK, (void *)j);;
        }
        /*Wait for threads to finish their jobs*/
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (countR < numb_count) while(pthread_cond_wait(&cond_var,&mutex) != 0);
        countR = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        /*Does more work*/
    }
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond_var);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {    
    /*Initialize threads*/
    InitTh(argv);

    /*Do some work*/
    FUNCTION();

    /*Treminate threads*/
    TermTh();

    return 0;
}
```

When `some_count`, (in my particular case,) is less than 76, the program works fine, but if I specify a larger value the program, as mentioned earlier, works for some time and then stalls. Maybe somebody can point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's the input you usually use in your runs? I mean what's is the value of Thread_count ?

Comment: so how do you expect to run 5 threads in the same time (j loop) when you malloc two to four?

Comment: Point taken. Thanks! I thought that the threads can do some work, e.g. two or four function executions, and then finish the rest (three or one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should init the thread number to `numb_count` rather then `argv`
then replace

```
 long thread = (long) j % thread_count;
```

with

```
 long thread = (long) j;
```

won't sure it fix it, but it's needed anyway...

Moreover, it's not about the number 76 or 77, you have a race condition in the thread use.
lets say that one of you threads got to the point in "DO_WORK" when he unlock the mutex but he still didn't returned from this function (meaning the thread is still running...). then you may try to create the same thread in the next iteration using:

```
pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL, DO_WORK, (void *)j);
```

fixing, change:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (countR < numb_count) while(pthread_cond_wait(&cond_var,&mutex) != 0);
    countR = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

to:

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (countR < numb_count) while(pthread_cond_wait(&cond_var,&mutex) != 0);
    countR = 0;
    for(long thread = 0; thread < numb_count; thread++)
        pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], NULL);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped, by that I mean that now programs works through a lot more loops, but still stalls in the end. May be there is another issue here. Thanks again, it was very helpful!

Comment: You should (If you didn't already) remove the for-loop from TermTH() or the program will stuck waiting for a thread to finish his work while no thread is running...

Comment: P.s. If the problem is solved please select the answer as "answer" so it will be close to prevent others for wasting time trying to solve it.

Comment: I have fixed the program and now it works fine and your advice was instrumental in this. Besides your corrections I moved the initialization of thread_handles into the loop inside of the FUNCTION(). Thank you, now it works like a charm. However, I don't understand the cause of this problem. Maybe you could comment on this?

Comment: I'm happy to hear that it works for you. a full explanation will be hard to give in this scope but basically one process can have some thread will each thread is doing something else. but a thread can only do one thing at a time. before the change you toke a thread in the middle of his work and told him to start working on something else leaving his first task unfinished.

Comment: UPDATE: I was a little bit hasty with the comment. Now it gives a segfault error.

Comment: Managed to fix. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
        long thread = (long) j % thread_count;
        pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL, DO_WORK, (void *)j);;
```

you can "override" initialized thread handles, depending on your actual thread count parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to analyze it using helgrind.

Install valgrind, then launch valgrind --tool=helgrind yourproject and see what helgrind spits out

Answer (score 1):

You are neither initializing your mutex correctly (not causing the error here), nor storing the threads you create correctly. Try this:

```
for(int count = 0; count < thread_count; ++count) {
    pthread_create(&thread_handles[count], NULL, DO_WORK, (void *)(count % numb_count));
}
```